# Using a custom form in a modelformset factory?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'd like to be able to use a customized form in a modelformset_factory. For example:

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Author
```

views.py

```
def test_render(request):
    myModelFormset = modelformset_factory(Author)
    items = Author.objects.all()
    formsetInstance = myModelFormset(queryset = items)
    return render_to_response('template',locals())
```

The above code works just fine, but note I'm NOT using AuthorForm. The question is how can I get the modelformset_factory to use the AuthorForm (which I plan to customize later) instead of making a default Author form?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you should be able to pass the custom model form like so:

```
myModelFormset = modelformset_factory(Author, form=AuthorForm)
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that by looking at the source shortly after I posted the question. I'm surprised I didn't stumble across that option in the documentation. Do you have a link to any documentation that indicates this is an option?

Comment: I think the closest the documentation comes to mentioning it is in saying that a ModelFormset is "just" a Formset that knows about the model, so you can use arguments from formset_factory in modelformset_factory.  The documentation for formset_factory says you can specify the form class.  It looks like there's a similar correspondence from modelformset_factory to inlineformset_factory.

Comment: here you have a link in the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/models/