# Django form with ManyToMany field with 500,000 objects times out

Tags: django, django-forms

Lets say for example I have a Model called "Client" and a model called "PhoneNumbers"

```
class PhoneNumbers(models.Model):
    number = forms.IntegerField()

class Client(models.Model):
    number = forms.ManyToManyField(PhoneNumbers)
```

Client has a ManyToMany relationship with PhoneNumbers. PhoneNumbers has almost 500,000 records in it so when it comes to editing a Client record from a model form with a MultiSelect widget that comes with a M2M filed, it takes forever to load. In fact, it never does. It just sits there trying to load all of those phone objects I am assuming.

My workaround was to so some tedious things with ajax and jquery to edit only the phone numbers in a Client record. Before wasting my time with all of that I wanted to see if there is somehow another way to go about it without having my page hang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a custom widget for this field that lets you autocomplete for the correct record. If you don't want to roll your own: http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/

*I've used this for its generic relationship support, the M2M autocomplete looks pretty easy and intuitive as well. see video of use here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJIHiqWKUXI&feature=youtu.be*

After reading your comment about needing it outside the admin, I took another look at the `django-autocomplete-light` library. [It provides widgets you can use outside the admin](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-outside-the-admin).

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django import forms

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'myformfield': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
                # ...
            ),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your update. I'm using a modelformset_factory using Django 1.3 which I dont believe allow the 'widget' kwarg to be passed through but I'll try to implement somehow and let you know the results.

Comment: modelformset_factory takes an option form object. `myModelFormset = modelformset_factory(Author, form=AuthorForm)` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853350/using-a-custom-form-in-a-modelformset-factory and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory

Answer (score 8):

Since Django 2.0, Django Admin ships with an [`autocomplete_fields` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) that generates autocomplete widgets for foreign keys and many-to-many fields.

```
class PhoneNumbersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['number']

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['number']
```

Note that this only works in the scope of Django admin of course. To get autocomplete fields outside the admin you would need an extra package such as [`django-autocomplete-light`](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) as already suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box, the model admin has a [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) option that let your page load much quicker. However, the user interface of raw id fields isn't very intuitive, so you might have to roll your own solution.

Comment: Yup, would be perfect, well sorta, if I only needed it in admin. However I require it to be within a template outside admin.

Answer (score 0):

We use this 3rd party widget for this:

https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects

Btw, your 'example' above is really bad DB design for a bunch of reasons.  You should just have the phone number as a text field on the Client model and then you would have none of these issues. ;-)